# am having a hard time getting my data from firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of trips that have a `departure`, `destination` and `vehicleID` which they got from the table `Vehicle` that has one too many association with trips that have name and type and `Driver`. How would I  display all of the trips with the name of the vehicle using flutter and fire base built with the MVC architecture?

this the model :

```
class Trips {
  String id;
  String departure;
  String destination;
  String vehicleID;

  Trips({required this.id, required this.departure, required this.destination, required this.vehicleID});
}

class Vehicle {
  String id;
  String name;
  String type;
  String Driver;

  Vehicle({required this.id, required this.name, required this.type, required this.Driver});
}
```

this is the controller

```
class TripsController {
  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Stream<List<Trips>> getTrips() {
    return _firestore
        .collection('trips')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
        .map((doc) => Trips(
      id: doc.id,
      departure: doc.data()?['departure'],
      destination: doc.data()?['destination'],
      vehicleID: doc.data()?['vehicleID'],
    ))
        .toList());
  }

  Future<Vehicle> getVehicle(String id) async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await _firestore.collection('vehicle').doc(id).get();
    return Vehicle(
      id: snapshot.id,
      Driver: (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)?['Driver'],
      name: (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)!['name'],
      type: (snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot)?['type'],
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the view :

```
class TripsView extends StatefulWidget {
  const TripsView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TripsView> createState() => _TripsViewState();
}

class _TripsViewState extends State<TripsView> {
  TripsController _controller = TripsController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Trips'),
      ),
      body: Stack(
         children:<Widget> [
           SizedBox(height: 30,),
           DropDownButton(),
           SizedBox(height: 80,),
      StreamBuilder<List<Trips>>(
          stream: _controller.getTrips(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              List<Trips>? trips = snapshot.data;
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: trips?.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(trips![index].departure),
                    subtitle: FutureBuilder<Vehicle>(
                      future: _controller.getVehicle(trips![index].vehicleID),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          Vehicle? vehicle = snapshot.data;
                          return Text(vehicle?.name??'');
                        } else {
                          return Text('Loading...');
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        ),
         ],),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know what the problem is with `getVehicle` it always shows loading instead of getting the vehicle name.
I need it to give me the vehicle name, is there a problem with `snapshot.hasData`?